# Magento - Top links "my cart" and "checkout" missing?

Tags: css, magento, checkout

The "my cart" and "checkout" links in the top links of my page are missing. In  `app/design/frontend/default/mobileshoppe/layout/checkout.xml` I do have this code:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
        <action method="addCartLink"></action>
        <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

So why else might my links be missing?

Comment: There is a possibility, maybe some other modules that you've installed earlier, edit this part of page. Did you search top.links in other xml files?

Comment: I edited your question to be clearer and more direct, please try to avoid unnecessary info for your problem and try to explain the issue concisely.

Answer (score 0):

Your `local.xml` file is the last xml file to get loaded so check that first to see if it contains something along the lines of;

```
<reference name="top.links">
  <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
     <url helper="checkout/cart"/>
  </action>
</reference>
```

or

```
<reference name="top.links">
  <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
</reference>
```

I would also check that other xml files in your themes `layout` folder for the code above.